# Laravel unique validation must include appended text when validating

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, request, laravel-validation

I am using the Laravel tenancy package in which there is a `domains` table in my database and each value in the `domain` column within this table is appended with `.test.co.uk.`

[image]

When the user enters the URL in the form, they are presented with an input element (shown above) in which they enter a URL/Domain but the `.test.co.uk` is already appended so the only thing they need to enter is the text that goes before that, e.g. they would enter `johnsmith` and in the `domain` column it would store `johnsmith.test.co.uk.` The problem I have is that I need the validation on this column to be unique but also include the `.test.co.uk` when performing the validation so that it looks at the value stored in the table because if a user enters `johnsmith` and there is currently a record in the `domains` table where the value is `johnsmith.test.co.uk` then the validation would pass but I need the validation to fail in this scenario. I am currently using a `Request` class which is extending the `FormRequest` class and have this:

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
       'url' => 'required|string|unique:domains,domain',
   ];
}
```

I have also tried a rule object but I don't think a rule object is the correct solution to this problem. Is there a convenient "Laravel" way of doing this?

Comment: Substitute .test.co.uk in the frontend and send it to the backend, it will be more correct and faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Request class use `prepareForValidation()`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#prepare-input-for-validation

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'url' => $this->url . '.test.co.uk',
    ]);
}
```